# Difference between country roads and streets

Tags: transport-fever

Country roads have a higher speed limit and are cheaper. Then, what are the benefits of streets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Cities will only place buildings on streets**.

Country (fast) roads in a city will be converted to city (slower) roads to allow the growth of the city.

- If you want to guide how a city is to grow, build with streets
- If you are trying to have a fast road for trucks to come into the city, build with the cheaper country roads